# how to use secret on machine where kubernetes cluster is installed?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I have created secret with username and password. Now I want to provide this credentials to other file in my host machine. To connect cloud storage for my cluster. How should I do it? Everywhere I can see how to use secrets on POD but not on host machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could mount the secret on a container using a [HostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volume, which would make it available in the node where it is running.

Comment: I think its not an option. I want to configure a connection from my cluster to external storage and I dont want it to be vulnerable to issues because pod will restart and credentials will be not available.

Comment: @DarkFurby Is there anything you have tried already? Could you please share some more details?